# get a value by the key from an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a static class `Tools`, where I defined a method `getMsg()` to retrieve a variable : array with keys and values:

```
private $Msg = array()

public static function getMsg()
{
    return $this->Msg;
}
```

Then I use this variable as follows in another class :

```
Tools::getMsg()['key'] = $this->message;
```

My question, I want to get the value by providing the key. I know about the php function

> array_search — Searches the array for a given value and returns the
>   first corresponding key if successful

But is there a function to search the array for a given key ?
I don't know if the syntax of my code above is correct so, if not I may need to use a function.

Here is an example of the Msg array :

```
$Msg = array('Class1' => 'File does not exist', 
'Class2' => 'Error in timestamp format')
```

Comment: array_column is what you are looking for ?

Comment: could you give an example of the Msg array, and an example of search ?

Comment: Uhm… `$this->Msg[$key]`…? Or `Tools::getMsg()[$key]`…?

Comment: @rahul_m no because I don't have arrays inside an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access an array, you do not need to use a built-in function. Simply access the array as follows.

```
$arr = array('foo' => 42, 'bar' => 'rab', 'baz' => false); // example array
echo $arr['bar']; // will output 'rab'
$key = 'foo';
echo $arr[$key]; // will output 42
```

As a sidenote: you cannot use `$this` in a static context. Use `self::$Msg` and declare `$Msg` as `private static $Msg`, or make the access not static at all. Your code could be along the following lines.

```
private static $Msg = array();

public static function getMsg()
{
    return self::$Msg;
}
```

Comment: please note that `$this-message` refers to another nonstatic class where I called the static one

Comment: Yes. Also, I was not referring to `$this->message`, but `$this->Msg` in your first example. I will edit to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
class Tools
{
    private static $Msg = [];

    public static function getMsg($key)
    {
        return self::$Msg[$key]
    }

}

$message = Tools::getMsg('test'); // returns Tools::$Msg['test']
```

I don't think there is a "static class" in PHP. Not sure about other languages though. use `self::` to access static properties/methods in the same class